# Setting an class attribute from child's class attributes when creating the object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to set an attribute for my object, but the value comes from a mathematical function that it's values will be get from the class child's classes.

I've tried using the method init on the constructor, but didn't

The main class:

```java
public abstract class Player {

    private double attackPower;
    private double defensePower;

    private double generalPower;

    // Getters and Setters

    // The method to set the generalPower
    private void setGeneralPower(){
        this.generalPower = defensePower + attackPower * 100;
    }
```

One of it's child class:

```java
public class Goalkeeper extends Player {

    private static final double DEFENSE_COEFFICIENT = 3.0;
    private static final double ATTACK_COEFFICIENT = 0.5;

    @Override
    public void setAttackPower(double attackPower) {
        super.setAttackPower(attackPower * ATTACK_COEFFICIENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefensePower(double defensePower) {
        super.setDefensePower(defensePower * DEFENSE_COEFFICIENT);
    }

}
```

When I'm inserting the mathematical function on the `getGeneralPower()`
the function returns the correct value, but I'll need the value to
be in an attribute to compare in the future.
If I insert the method on the constructor I'm getting a 0.0 value.
If I use the init method on the constructor and call `setGeneralPower()` from the init body, it is also giving me a 0.0 result.

**The reason for having a `setGeneralPower()` is to set the value of `generalPower` attribute.**

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But I'll need this value as a attribute of the object to further comparison, there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shouldn't even have a `setGeneralPower()` method.

Instead, give the class a getter method, `public double getGeneralPower()` that calculates and returns the appropriate value. Make it a *calculated* property, one that calls appropriate overridable methods if need be.

e.g.,

```
public abstract class Player {

    private double attackPower;
    private double defensePower;

    // **** get rid of this and make it a calculated property
    // private double generalPower;

    public double getGeneralPower() {
        return 100 * getAttackPower() + getDefensePower();
    }
```

Otherwise, if you forget to call the setter (non-setter method, really), the method gives an incorrect answer. This way, the return value is guaranteed to be up-to-date and correct.

Regarding your update:

> **The reason for having a `setGeneralPower()` is to set the value of `generalPower` attribute.**

**Again** ***DON'T*** give the class a generalPower field and the problem is solved.

Again remember that general power has the potential to change if either defense or attack power are changed, so you must protect your code against this happening. If the coder who uses this class -- someone else or your future self -- forgets to call that setter right before the getter, they are in deep trouble.

Note that even *without* a generalPower *field* it remains an *attribute* or *property* of the class, a calculated one, but a valid (and *safe*) one.

Comment: Could you show me some piece of code as example? I din't understand very well what you told me.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza: general power has the potential to change if either defense or attack power are changed, so you must protect your code against this happening. If the coder who uses this class -- someone else or your future self -- forgets to call that setter right before the getter, they are in deep trouble.

Comment: Ohh! I tough about it, but there's a way to set this to be the value of and attribute of the class?

Comment: @JohnnesSouza: please listen to reason. Yes, it can be done if you add code to the setter methods in the `setDefensePower(...)` and `setAttackPower(...)` that updates the general power field but that unnecessarily complicates things, leading to risk of bugs. Just don't do it.

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out I understood! So I'll have the comparison by hand in the future.